# i2cdump works but not i2cget

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I am trying to use a BMP180 over i2c on a Raspberry Pi.

I detect the chip. I can take a i2cdump, but I cannot read out a single byte.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Print out:

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 77

$ sudo i2cdump -y 1 0x77
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: XX XX XX XX XX 00 XX 00 XX XX XX 00 XX XX 00 XX    XXXXX.X.XXX.XX.X
10: 00 XX XX 00 XX XX 00 XX 00 XX 00 XX 00 XX 00 XX    .XX.XX.X.X.X.X.X
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
80: a5 94 48 09 2a 27 78 7b 8a 7e 1f 05 fb b0 c7 c2    ??H?*'x{?~??????
90: 82 18 63 d2 4c b8 19 73 00 28 80 00 d1 f6 09 b2    ??c?L??s.(?.????
a0: a5 94 48 09 2a 27 78 7b 8a 7e 1f 05 fb b0 c7 c2    ??H?*'x{?~??????
b0: 82 18 63 d2 4c b8 19 73 00 28 80 00 d1 f6 09 b2    ??c?L??s.(?.????
c0: 00 00 bc 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 03    ..?3.......?...?
d0: 55 02 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    U??.............
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ......?.........

$ sudo i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0
Error: Read failed
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have exactly the same issue but with a different chip.

Comment: I believe the XX in the dump also mean the read failed.

Answer (score 3):

You first have to set-up the control registers.
For a BME280 (I suppose it is the same for the BME180), one has to write:

```
$ i2cset -y 1 0x76 0xF2 0x01
$ i2cset -y 1 0x76 0xF4 0x25
$ i2cdump -y -r 0xF7-0xFE 1 0x76 c
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
f0:                      6d 72 00 86 68 00 59 bb              mr.?h.Y?
```

The first 2 writes set oversampling x1 to all channels.
The second additionally starts a single conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same with my MPU-9250. First I thought like F Corthay that I need to write first, setting the sensors to "on" and "listen". However, usually, on my other Raspberry, it worked w/o this preparation step.
I did try it but I got also a write error.

And at the end...... it turned out that the GROUND wire slipped off. This was weird as i2cdump was still working but as soon as I wanted to read a specific register with i2cget or trying to write with i2cset, the error was thrown.

So, sometimes it is a physical reason. Check the GND wire ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your wire connections? Be careful there is a pin between `SCL` and `GND`.
I had the same error when I connected `GND` wire to the `GPIO 4` pin (I was using `BME280`).

[image]

And a successful output from `i2cdump` should be like this (`XXX` in the beginning may indicate some error as @Pepijn said):

```
i2cdump -y 1 0x77
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
80: 8a 70 89 57 6a 20 a0 26 7e 6e f0 67 32 00 3d 96    ?p?Wj ?&~n?g2.=?
90: bc d6 d0 0b 1a 0f df ff f9 ff ac 26 0a d8 bd 10    ???????.?.?&????
a0: 00 4b 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 00 00 c0    .KB.........3..?
b0: 00 54 00 00 00 00 60 02 00 01 ff cf 1f 60 03 00    .T....`?.?.??`?.
c0: 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
d0: 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    `...............
e0: 00 6d 01 00 13 27 03 1e 6a 41 ff cf ff cf ff cf    .m?.?'??jA.?.?.?
f0: ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 80 00 00 80 00 80    .......?..?..?.?
```